# "The connection has been reset"

Tags: drupal-7, installation, wamp

I have copied a Drupal site from a live server to a test environment in order to do further development. I have set this up in a WAMP environment, importerted databases successfully and setup af a virtual host for the site.

I can connect to the site without problems and login. When I want to access the admin pages, I get the following message from the browser (http://www.MYSITE.local/da/admin/modules):

```
The connection has been reset
```

Firefox reports the request as "Aborted" when I inspect Firebug's Net.

There are no errors in the Apache log files. Also, I have enabled PHP errors for debugging, and nothing is displayed.

I have reset cache, looked for compression settings for CSS and Javascript in phpMyAdmin, but not found any I could disable.

Help is much appriciated!

Comment: Is your MySQL `max_allowed_packet` set at 1mb by any chance?

Comment: Yes. I've changed it to 64 MB, even though that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a migration if you are facing problem, then run  [rebuild_registry](http://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) and its solved. **Please note that its not a module for drupal.** It is available as a very helpful submodule for drush.

I highly recommend installing drush manually for windows. Follow the [instruction](http://drupal.org/node/594744) to install drush.

After installation run,

```
drush dl registry_rebuild
```

It doesn't matter from which directory you run this command, since its a drush extention and not a drupal extention.  Drush will download the required files and place it in the appropriate location.

once its done, you can visit your sites folder and run

```
drush rr
```

That should rebuild the registry and clear the cache. Most of the migration issues are fixed automatcially.  Please leave a comment if it doesn't fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

If it didn't help - like in my case, add following code to your httpd.conf This will increase the stack size (default 1MB)

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
  ThreadStackSize 8388608
</IfModule>
```

Comment: My apache doesn't have such file (httpd.conf ) Where shall I put this?

Answer (score 0):

Truncate manually all caches table and the sessions one could solve:

for example:

```
Truncate table myprefix_cache;
Truncate table myprefix_cache_admin_menu;
Truncate table myprefix_cache_block;
Truncate table myprefix_cache_bootstrap;
Truncate table myprefix_cache_field;
Truncate table myprefix_cache_filter;
Truncate table myprefix_cache_form;
Truncate table myprefix_cache_image;
Truncate table myprefix_cache_l10n_update;
Truncate table myprefix_cache_libraries;
Truncate table myprefix_cache_media_xml;
Truncate table myprefix_cache_menu;
Truncate table myprefix_cache_page;
Truncate table myprefix_cache_path;
Truncate table myprefix_cache_rules;
Truncate table myprefix_cache_token;
Truncate table myprefix_cache_update;
Truncate table myprefix_cache_variable;
Truncate table myprefix_cache_views;
Truncate table myprefix_cache_views_data;
Truncate table myprefix_sessions;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that by visiting Performance and disabling Aggregate and Compress CSS.